# how to install python and modules(XlsWriter, Pandas. etc) from C# wpf application

Tags: python, c#

I have a WPF application that requires python 3.6.150 and other libraries like pandas and XlsWriter.
currently the python installation is done manually by downloading and running the installer.
what I have tried:
I have set a variables to get the path where python is installed and run commands. However I am sure there are better ways to do this.

```cs
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        
string pathFull = path + @"\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts";
string installXlsWriter = "pip install XlsxWriter";
string installNumpy = "pip install numpy";
string installPandas = "pip install pandas";

// install xlswriter
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",installXlsWriter);
```